# C converts .txt to binary file using System Calls

Tags: c, data-conversion

I'm writing a program that replaces every character where `position % step = 0`
As command line arguments I'm giving `1. file` `2. character` and `3. step`. I can only use system calls. Here is my main function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

   assert(argc ==  4);

   int fdInput = open(argv[1], O_WRONLY);
   if(fdInput == -1)
      fatalError("Error opening input file.\n");

   char c[1];
   c[0] = argv[2][0];
   unsigned step = atoi(argv[3]);

   int fileSize;
   if((fileSize = lseek(fdInput,0,SEEK_END)) < 0)
      fatalError("Lseek error: Determining file size\n");

   if(lseek(fdInput,0,SEEK_SET) == -1)
      fatalError("Lseek error: Returning to the beginning\n");

   int i;
   for(i = 0; i*step < fileSize; i++)

      if(step - 1 > 0){
         if(lseek(fdInput, i*step - 1, SEEK_SET) == -1)
            fatalError("Lseek error: Within loop\n");

         if(write(fdInput, c, 1) != 1)
            fatalError("Writing error\n");

      }
      else {

         if(write(fdInput, c, 1) != 1)
            fatalError("Writing error.\n");
      }
      close(fdInput);
      return 0;
   }
```

**Example:**

> input.txt: 123456789

`./output input.txt x 3` would return `12x45x78x`

**Problem:** For some reason, when I compile and execute for the first time, *everything works fine*! BUT: when I execute it for the second time, it won't work. When I try to `cat/less` `input.txt` it tells me that file is binary.

- `echo "123456789" > input.txt` -> creates `.txt` file
- `./output input.txt x 3` -> `12x45x78x`
- `./output input.txt x 3` -> won't work (program is finished), but:
- `less input.txt` -> `input.txt" may be a binary file.  See it anyway?`

How can file be binary? It should be plain text file. What am I doing wrong here? Am I doing something wrong with `open`?

Comment: First thing I've noticed is that for me even first execution doesn't work properly. File seems to be filled with tons of null character ( but replaced string looks fine ). I will continue investigation.

Comment: wow, I've realized you are generating with this piece of code 4GB sparse file.

Comment: In first lseek in a loop you make huge jump:

lseek(3, 4294967295, SEEK_SET)          = 4294967295
write(3, "x", 1)                        = 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first seek offset is wrong:

```
i*step - 1
```

with `i == 0` this yields `-1`, considering only the pure mathematical calculation and leaving implicit type casts out of the game. This is then converted to an `unsigned` (`off_t` is signed and a negative value passed should lead to `EINVAL`, thus it has to be the implicit conversion) which is going to be extremely large (`UINT_MAX`). The result is an extremely large (but sparse) file.

Oh, and:

```
assert(argc ==  4);
```

`assert` is meant to check invariants, not for handling incorrect user input.

Comment: "with i == 0 this yields -1" is not so.  `int*unsigned - int` --> `unsigned`.  So "with i == 0 should yield `UINT_MAX`

Comment: Hm, I need to explain this better. What I meant is that the *mathematical* calculation yields `-1`. I wasn't sure whether signed * unsigned would yield an unsigned result, though, which is why I didn't state it. I wanted to check in the standard when I'm online via my laptop, and not my mobile.

Comment: `i*step - 1` is not mathematical calculated without considering type and _then_ converted to an `unsigned`.  At each step, the value and tpye are considered.  `(int)0 * (unsigned)step` --> `(unsigned)0`.  `(unsigned)0 - (int)1` --> `UINT_MAX`.  If `UINT_MAX` is in the range of `off_t`, then a large positive value is passed to `lseek()`.  Else if it is out of range, the result is not defined (UB).  IAC, you have well identified a problem of OP's code.  It is just that the "why" is  amiss.  Your edit improved and is closer to the reason.

Comment: Thank you both for answering.

Comment: Just one more thing, why does it convert .txt to binary?

Comment: less notices that there are lots of non printable characters, thus it guesses that it might be a file not intended for viewing it directly. There are no such things as "binary files" (all files are binary); there's no conversion. (Binary is an open mode that affects the way certain byte sequences are interpreted on certain platforms)

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize i to 1 instead of 0 i.e.

```
for(i = 1; i*step < fileSize; i++)
```

Otherwise, as @Daniel Jour said, your first seek offset will be wrong (i*step - 1 == -1, considering only the pure mathematical calculation and leaving implicit type casts out of the game).

Also, you should add *for-loop*'s opening and closing braces for better legibility.

Comment: "first seek offset will be wrong (i*step - 1 == -1)" --> `0*step - 1 --> UINT_MAX`.

Comment: @chux Updated my answer to reflect Daniel Jour's one. I was meaning the same. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for answering.